# All sytax is correct in css regarding bg-image but not getting display

Tags: html, css

I am not able to get background image in html div url is correct all syntax is correct.

HTML

`<div class="img-container"></div>`

CSS

```
.img-container {
   background-image: url("../img/photosm.jpg");
 }
```

Comment: Make sure that path to image is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test one of two things,

1. make sure the path to the image is correct. In devtools network tab you can see if the image loads correctly.
2. using image as background will not make the container inherit the image height and width. It need to have its own so to speak. So try to set a height/width.

```
.img-container {
   background-image: url("../img/photosm.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 20rem;
   width: 30rem;
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked as you mentioned the problem associated with height and width. Thank you very much for clarification